# How can I import sms from iphone 4s / IOS6 with Samsung Kies

Tags: sms, samsung-kies, ios, data-transfer, import

I've got a brand spanking Samsung Galaxy Note 2 and I want to import my SMS's - I've installed Kies, detected an iphone backup, (my iphone's name and date displays) but the import screen just refreshes infinitely (hmm... probably infinite) whilst my fans get to cranking (activity monitor shows 30% CPU).

My iphone backup is fresh, unencrypted, and I've tried with the phone plugged in,  itunes running + iphone plugged in, and ihpone / itunes disconnected.

Any insider tips for me?!

(Please note, this question is IOS6 dependant - other tips for IOS5 haven't worked for me)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I migrate my SMS (text messages) from iPhone to Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38960/how-do-i-migrate-my-sms-text-messages-from-iphone-to-android)

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as a duplicate, since Kies is involved. (The other question is on a non-Samsung phone, so Kies can't possibly be involved.)

Comment: also, that question addresses IOS5, and the techniques documented aren't working on my IOS6 phone, tx

Comment: Also related or possible duplicate: [How to transfer text messages from iPhone to Android with iOS 5](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16019/how-to-transfer-text-messages-from-iphone-to-android-with-ios-5)

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from Samsung - was instructed to 'Update Drivers' or some such from the Window or Tools menu.

So, this worked for me - got the text components of my SMS history, then uninstalled Kies due to a conflict with Android File transfer on OSX 10.8.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this same problem and have a Samsung phone, try http://www.samsung.com/us/smart-switch/

It may not have been available when you initially posted the original question, but I just upgraded from an iPhone 5 with iOS 6 to a Samsung Galaxy S4.  I wanted to copy over my SMS messages and found that most only worked with iOS 5 and below. This worked perfectly (Kies for some reason did not provide an option to transfer my messages).  It also copied over my MMS messages.