# How do I migrate my SMS (text messages) from iPhone to Android?

Tags: sms, ios, data-transfer, import

I want to **export my SMS history from an iPhone and import them into a new Android phone,** including timestamp, message direction (incoming|outgoing), and correspondent (sender or recipient).

My specific scenario is this, but perhaps a generic solution exists -
*Source:* iPhone 4 running iOS 5 (jailbroken, if it helps)
*Target:* LG Nexus 4

<sub>[This old question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16019/how-to-transfer-text-messages-from-iphone-to-android-with-ios-5) seems relevant except that it's aimed at Samsung devices, and it's 1½ years old.

Also, there's this alarming comment:

*The problem with faked.org/isms2droid is that it doesn't correctly extract the iMessages correctly. It gets the wrong timestamp, and leaves the address empty and the type (which represents sent or received) is always 1 (received).*</sub>

I'm thinking that there could be newer solutions that are worth mentioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging into google, I came across a software called **[Backuptrans](http://www.backuptrans.com/android-iphone-sms-transfer-plus.html)**. The features listed include Transfer SMS between Android and iPhone, Save SMS from Android/iPhone onto local database on computer, Restore SMS from local database to Android/iPhone and many more.

I do not have an iPhone to check this software. This seems pretty good. The work steps are as simple as importing from iPhone to the computer and exporting to the Android device. More details with screenshots can be found **[here](http://www.backuptrans.com/tutorial/how-to-transfer-text-messages-from-iphone-to-android.html)**

The only downer for this solution is that you have to pay some cash (a minimum of $29.95) to use it fully. Since you are not comfortable with [iSMS2droid (iPhone SMS Import)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.faked.isms2droid&hl=en), this seems to be the best option available.

<sup>On an additional note, [iSMS2droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.faked.isms2droid&hl=en) is worth trying before you buy [Backuptrans](http://www.backuptrans.com/android-iphone-sms-transfer-plus.html).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way you can refer to transfer SMS messages from old iPhone to new Android.

1. Use iCloud to backup your SMS
2. Then connect Android phone to your computer
3. Open the iCloud backup file and copy those SMS to Android phone

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9357/sms-backup-in-android/9434#9434) to a previous SMS backup and restore question suggests that [Very Android SMS Backup](http://www.veryandroid.com/sms-backup.html) should be able to do this. They have a guide on how to do it here: [How to transfer SMS to Android from iPhone, Windows Mobile, Nokia, Blackberry etc?](http://www.veryandroid.com/how-to-transfer-sms-to-android-from-iphone-windows-mobile-nokia-etc.html)