# Newbie to android needs help transferring texts from iPhone to new Pixel 7 after setup

Tags: sms, google, file-transfer, ios

all. My only smartphone experience is with an old iPhone 6S someone gave me. My 92yo MIL's landlline went down and won't be back up for a while (we're in the country--things take forever), so we decided to get a cell phone for her, and one for my husband while we were at it. We got Pixel 7s because that's what came free with the two new lines. Then we decided I would get one of the Pixel 7s and give her my old iPhone because the iPhone is less complicated to use. Android has been a huge learning curve for us after using iPhone for so long.

Our carrier is T-Mobile, and the phones were set up at the store. Needless to say, some data was not transferred to the Pixel 7 from the iPhone and the setup process is now "finished". How can I transfer text messages from iPhone to Pixel 7 at this point? I would like to get all my data off the iPhone so I can clean it up and give it to my MIL. She lives along and I don't like her being without a phone.

I may be a newbie to Android, but I have done some computer programming (enough to be dangerous) and capable of following directions and not (too) afraid to do so.

Please don't tell me to do a factory reset. I have spent a fair amount of time downloading apps and making sure I can log into them again.

Thanks in advance, everyone, for your assistance.

--Elizabeth

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We have some older questions about the same situation: [How do I migrate my SMS (text messages) from iPhone to Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/16019/44325), [How do I migrate my SMS (text messages) from iPhone to Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/38960/44325). Perhaps you might want to have a read and consider the existing solutions from there.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I'll take a look at those.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. It took a bit of trial and error but the iSMS2Droid app worked!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Since one of the answers solves your issue, I'll close this question as a duplicate of the existing question to indicate that the issue has been solved.